# HTML/CSS div is not fitting in div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with CSS and HTML I cannot understand why this is happening

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_conteiner">
      <div id="logo_container">
        <img src="images/logo.png" /> 
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="text_input" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background:#787777;
    font-family:"Droid Sans",Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    font-size:0.81em;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#header{
    height:100px;
    background:#000000;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px solid #6F3;
}

#header_conteiner{
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #9F0;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#logo_container{
    padding-top:3px;
    width:237px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #03F;
}

#txtSearch{
    width:220px;
    height:20px; float:right;
}
```

**Here is result:**
[image]

as you see in image input text is out of `header_conteiner` can anyone advice me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to #header_conteiner:

```
  float: left;
  clear: both;
```

So result is this:

```
#header_conteiner{
  width:1000px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #9F0;
  margin:0 auto;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Move the input *before* the logo container.

Comment: Thank you it worked but still cannot understand why html works this way

Comment: Because the input element is actually placed under the logo container and then you tell it to float right. If you put input first, then it will float right, not taking the space for the logo container, which can remain up.

Comment: Simply put, if you want more block elements to be placed next to each other, the floating elements must go first. Any floating elements placed _after_ non-floating element will be placed below it.

Comment: And thats because floats are first set like any other element and then removed from its container's flow. If you set it afterwards, the div before will expand all the way to the right, hence using the pixels above the search box. So when you float it afterwards, only the pixels below the div will be available for floated element to place itself.

Answer (score 1):

logo_container is a div, a block element. Meaning it takes up the horizontal space in its container; the next HTML element will be forced below it. As logo_container is set to 100px, the same as header_conteiner, there is no vertical space left for your input box. It is forced below logo_container.

To fix the problem, you could make logo_container an inline element and float it left. Inline elements can sit next to each other, whilst block-line elements need their own horizontal space.

CSS display property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

it looks like logo_container has a padding on top of 3px